# local html file showing blank on some Android devices

Tags: android, html, image, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

My Android app needs to display an Html file that is stored on the local SD card. The html file is rather simple, here is the source code. It shows fine on some devices, but on some devices it is just blank(both are on Kitkat). I suspect it is somehow on these devices the webview can not show the image list(the img object) correctly. Any suggestions what can fix it by either change some of the settings for the webview or the html source code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      img{
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        margin-bottom: 22px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body><img src="pi/pi_0.png" alt="">
<img src="pi/pi_1.png" alt="">
<img src="pi/pi_2.png" alt="">
<img src="pi/pi_3.png" alt="">
<img src="pi/pi_4.png" alt="">
<img src="pi/pi_5.png" alt="">
<img src="pi/pi_6.png" alt="">
<img src="pi/pi_7.png" alt="">
<img src="pi/pi_8.png" alt="">
<img src="pi/pi_9.png" alt="">
<img src="pi/pi_10.png" alt="">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try with low size images?

Comment: can you try to add some text to the html? Then you know if your file isn't loading or if it's just a problem with the images.

Comment: I suspect your problem is all about those image path. Would you accept to run this test: to convert your image to inline image using a technique like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

If this work then you will know as fact that was the problem

Answer (score 3):

Though it should work fine on all devices. In order to debug the actual cause, you need to use [chrome remote debugging tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews). With these tools it should be easy to identify the cause.

From the docs:

> Debug WebViews in your native Android apps using Chrome Developer
>   Tools.
>
> On Android 4.4 (KitKat) or later, use DevTools to debug WebView
>   content in native Android applications.

You need to put the following code in the file where the webview is used:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

And to open it

```
chrome://inspect
```

Some useful links for further information:

[Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging)

[A Tutorial](https://medium.com/bpxl-craft/how-to-debug-android-webview-content-526f7c4bf665)

Comment: Although this is not a direct answer for the question but it is the most useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is on SD card as you said then try to use full path to file. Pattern like `file:///sdcard/folder/pi/pi_1.png`. And this path may be different for every phone. So first, try to find out what path to this file in Java/Kotlin code. And then loadHtml where you have correct full path to file. If your image files are in assets folder than you should do the same and use full path, not relative

Comment: Loading a single image is ok. This particular html file loads an images list with 10 images. It works on most devices but not on some.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are loading them from external storage, you must add permissions to do so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And if you are using try this for the URL:

```
String url = "file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "content/myFile.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and worked for me even in android API 19 (kitkat):

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 235;

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);

        if (checkPermission()) {
            loadHtmlFile();
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }

    }


    private boolean checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    loadHtmlFile();
                } else {
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void loadHtmlFile() {
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Log.d("tag", "No SDCARD");
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.html");

        }
    }

}
```

make sure files is exist in right place:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Allow following in your webview.**

```
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```